Cannot upload file to AWS s3 by laravel
I get this error when I try to upload file in s3 bucket Unable to write file at location: example.txt.
Route::get('test', function () {
    try {
        Storage::disk('s3')->put('example.txt', 'Hello, world!');
        echo "File written successfully.";
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        Log::error("Unable to write file to S3: " . $e->getMessage(), ['exception' => $e]);
        echo "Unable to write file to S3: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
});

'test' => [
            'driver' => 's3',
            'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
            'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
            'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
            'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
            'url' => env('AWS_URL'),
            'endpoint' => env('AWS_ENDPOINT'),
            'use_path_style_endpoint' => env('AWS_USE_PATH_STYLE_ENDPOINT', false),
            'throw' => true,
            'visibility' => 'public',
            'root' => 'test'
        ],

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=AKIAZI**********WINWQ
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=1v52zNWBnDK4*************YrmgZQ7Q8kCs3
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_BUCKET=ductn-test
AWS_URL=https://ductn-test.console.aws.amazon.com/
AWS_USE_PATH_STYLE_ENDPOINT=false

Have anyone know how to solve this problem. Thank you!
I try to change 'throw' => true, in config/filesystem.php and I got this problem

Please include the exact error(and traceback).  Also, do you have permission to write to the bucket?  I'm assuming you're uploading to the root container of the bucket(i.e. the path is /), so do you have write permission there?

I see everyone public access in ACL but cannot choose write just read and list. Also, I give s3FullAccess to the user. In CORS I using this [
{
"AllowedHeaders": [],
"AllowedMethods": [
"GET",
"PUT",
"POST",
"DELETE"
],
"AllowedOrigins": [
"*"
],
"ExposeHeaders": []
}
]
